# How does Virtualization works internally?

Tags: operating-system, virtualization, hypervisor

I was reading about virtualization and a doubt popped in my head. How does virtualization works internally at Operating System level? The topic was discussed in my class and I came across this.

**A virtual box runs like a process with some extra privileges on the host operating system.**

My doubt is, If VM is running as a process then who provides this extra privilege to it so that it could actually interfere with the underlying OS and hardware resources.

I read what a Hypervisor is: http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/hypervisor

A hypervisor is the connection between VM and host OS. Running hypervisor on a host OS means we will run it as a user process. Again my doubt is the same.

How can a user process (which is a hypervisor) control the host processor and resources? As far as I knew user processes dont have those rights.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It all depends on the platform and implementation. I don't think most implementations give the user process total control of the host processor and resources, the virtualization implementation just emulates it. For instance if the guest wants to display something on the screen, the guest is convinced that it's interfacing with a hardware GPU, but the VM just intercepts the communication and would just use API's on the host to display it like a regular user process. But again, it is all implementation-dependent, for instance there are x86-specific mechanisms specifically for VM's.